# With a perfect square containing one quadrant of a perfect circle, can it be easily determined whether a point is inside the circle?

Tags: geometry

Diagram: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEg5i.jpg
[image]

This is an easy problem if you compute the distance from the corner of the square at the center of the circle (just whether `d` is less-than-or-equal to `r`), but is it possible to determine from the point opposite that one without computing the distance from the circle's center.

The context is for image processing. I have the four outer corners of a bounding box but any algorithmic solution becomes complex when you need to compute which part of the bounding box a particular point is. However, I know that every point is inside the bounding box, so I'm wondering if it's possible to measure the distance from all four outer points and determine if a point would lie outside a circle based on its distance from those four corners.

Comment: You don't need the distance to the centre of the circle, you can compute the *squared* distance, which avoids the expensive square root function call.

Comment: Do you know the angle between the dotted line and any one of the four sides of the square?

Answer (score 1):

For distances to two adjacent vertices:
$$
d_1^2=(r-x)^2+(r-y)^2,\qquad d_2^2=(r+x)^2+(r-y)^2
$$
so one can find that,
$$
2(x^2+y^2) = d_1^2 + d_2^2 - \sqrt{(2r+d_1+d_2)(d_1+d_2-2r)(2r+d_1-d_2)(2r+d_2-d_1)}
$$

From $2(x^2+y^2)>2r^2$, we find the critertion for the point to be out of the cirle:
$$
d_1^2 + d_2^2 - \sqrt{(2r+d_1+d_2)(d_1+d_2-2r)(2r+d_1-d_2)(2r+d_2-d_1)} > 2r^2
$$

Or if you simplify:
$$
d_1^4+d_2^4 +10r^4 > 6(d_1^2+d_2^2)r^2.
$$